# How to implement detail-master in lists

Tags: list, list-view, master-detail

I need to store articles in a document library. The problem is that an article can have more than one authors and one author can have more than one article - we have n-n relationship. Moreover, the authors are in some order (for a specific article). The problem is that I need to filter by author at the document library.

What should be the best strategy?

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to:

a) create a lookup field(multiple values) in list articles, pointing to authors.

b) create a lookup field (multiple values) in list authors, pointing to articles.

In that way I can have the two lists (whichever is first) and connect the two lists.